# problem running jboss 5.1.0

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I try to run (call run.bat from bin directory) jboss 5.1.0 on win7 x64, and got lots of exceptions ([here](http://pastebin.com/ELTwbVzv))
If I run the same jboss (literally extracted from the same zip archive) on another machine (win xp x86) it works great.

May be some compatibility issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayby you can check what happen if you place JBoss in directory without `!` mark?

There is bug in JVM reported in 2001: [getResourceAsStream on jars in path with "!"](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4523159) and it seems its still unresolved.

You can also check what happen when you extract JBoss archive using WinZip. I have some problem when I extract JBoss archive using standard tools (it was few year ago in Windows XP, and maybe it is not the issue).